# What is the current percent of traffic from Bing to Stackoverflow and Serverfault?

Tags: discussion, search

This would be a question directed at one of the inside guys, but I was wondering what the current percent of traffic is coming from Microsoft's new search engine.

Comment: Googling with Bing http://www.collegehumor.com/video:1915736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really low.

You can see some stats here; nothing has really changed since then, except the names.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001224.html

(Well, it's not true that *nothing* has changed, Google is now up to about 90% of our overall traffic..)

Basically, if all the other search engines (other than Google) on the planet were destroyed in a fiery cataclysm, it would make virtually no difference to our traffic at all.

Answer (score 0):

MediaPost: [Bing's Growth Accelerates](http://www.mediapost.com/publications/article/109514/)

> *Adding in Live.com and MSN Search along with Bing, the combined search engines have grown at an average of 16 percent during June 2009. Hitwise estimates that Bing grew faster than the three other prominent search engines for the month.*

I happen to LOVE the commercials... but I don't *'bing* as often as I *google* though. Habit.

[image]

([Source](http://www.industrialsearchenginemarketing.com/blog/2009/06/29/is-bing-msn-driving-more-traffic-to-industrial-websites/))

Comment: I appreciate the link.  But I was hoping (pipe dream maybe) for a pie chart or something of the sort.

Comment: Found you a nice and pretty chart :)

Comment: My bad.  I'm guessing you though I meant search traffic to any site.  I meant only to SO.  Oh well, that's an interesting chart none the less.